# Can Cellebrite be used to access any phone by the government? What is the point of encryption if they can get into any phone?

Tags: encryption, forensics, data-recovery, surveillance, government

I'm currently studying forensics, and one thing that keeps coming up is the authorities breaking into phones.

There are several third party tools they can use, but one of the most popular is 'Cellebrite'.

My understanding of this device was that they could NOT access an encrypted, password protected phone BFU (before first unlock), as long as it was a modern device and the firmware was updated to the most recent version.

But time and time again, the police are able to crack any phone they want. It takes time sometimes, but they get in there eventually.

There was even a case not too long ago where they couldn't easily access the iphone they had seized, so they went to Apple's HQ and Apple unlocked it for them.

I assume Samsung would comply with the police as well.

Not to mention the stack of backdoors or zero day bootrom exploits the intelligence agencies could be sitting on.

So what is the point of encryption in regards to law enforcement, really? If they are getting in either way, why even bother?

How can one ensure their device is 100% (or even 99.9%) protected? Buy a Chinese phone? But then you have to worry about surveillance from China. Not to mentioned the hardware exploits that could be used.

Extending this to computers, what is the point of even having things like VeraCrypt or Bitlocker exist if the government can go to the manufacturer and get them to crack it open? If they can utilize zero days and hardware and bios exploits every time?

Comment: I think you have a few facts wrong. "the police are able to crack any phone they want" -- citation needed. Apple did not unlock a phone. Samsung wouldn't be the one contacted to unlock a phone; Google would be. Veracrypt can't unlock a container. Things are not as binary (yes/no) and you appear to think they are.

Comment: The question reads as: "if someone with enough money and time can break into some devices, what's the point of securing them?" The answer is simply because it takes time and money, and there is no guarantee of success.

Comment: @schroeder I disagree. Having a warrant IS binary. You either have it or you do not.

https://toronto.ctvnews.ca/police-went-to-apple-offices-to-access-rob-ford-friend-s-iphone-1.1743787

Here is a source. You can use google to see that it has happened before as well. My question was attempting to lead the conversation into cryptography that can withstand any time and any amount of money.

Comment: Warrants are completely beside the point. And warrants don't magically empower anyone do accomplish technical tasks ...

Comment: And that article you linked says nothing of encryption or what was required to extract the data. Nor does it say that the device was unlocked. You're jumping to too many conclusions.

Comment: @schroeder Warrants are based on something we call the law, which anything within the country has to obey. Sometimes we need to draw conclusions with what we have, and that's what I have done. They did get the data, and they got it after visiting the Apple HQ. They wouldn't have needed to go there if the encryption wasn't strong, and they wouldn't have gotten the data if Apple hadn't unlocked it for them.

Comment: No need to be patronising. A warrant does not enable any party to break encryption.  It only provides legal permission to attempt it. So, no, your comment about the warrant isn't relevant.

Comment: Here's info from Apple: https://www.apple.com/customer-letter/answers/#:~:text=Has%20Apple%20unlocked%20iPhones%20for,to%20these%20requests%2024%2F7.  So, yes, you are jumping to conclusions and you have several facts incorrect. That makes this difficult to answer without challenging your initial premise.

Comment: If you look up what the Apple case was actually about it did not involve the FBI wanting Apple to break their own encryption. It was a request for Apple to create a modified version of IOS to allow the FBI to try and brute force the password (basically a version of IOS that doesn't lock you out after n attempts). In so far as a warrants go, they can compel someone (say Apple) to break their encryption but as @schroeder pointed out it doesn't magically acheive it - if Apple CAN'T break their own encryption then the warrant is meaningless.

Comment: @schroeder I think my comment about the warrant IS relevant, as I already used this article: https://toronto.ctvnews.ca/police-went-to-apple-offices-to-access-rob-ford-friend-s-iphone-1.1743787 which says a lot about what can and cannot be done with the warrant. Your other argument is encryption, and again, we must connect the dots. IF you don't think Apple can get around their own encryption then I disagree with you, because that seems like a very unlikely thing.

Comment: @user2334659 I was talking more about a famous Canadian case based on a Canadian warrant linked above.

Comment: You have some magical thinking about warrants. And my Apple link above suggests other reasons why Apple could get data from a device. So, if you want to connect dots, then you can't ***reject*** relevant dots. Only choosing dots that support your pre-existing conclusions is called "Confirmation Bias". So, again, this question will be difficult to answer without challenging your initial premise.

Comment: The point of encryption is to keep normal bad guys out. 99% of criminals don't have access to the tools of the government so encryption blocks them.

Comment: Shcroeder i've literally presented an entire Canadian case which supports my dots and you haven't so much as commented on it. You're just trying to poke holes in the logical side of my argument, but logic supports me. If you have other dots to share, I am more than willing to look at them, but so far your argument has been based on heavy speculation. Speculation is necessary, yes, but basing your entire line of thinking on it can be detrimental to the overall quality of your argument.

Comment: There is no "entire" case there. That's a summary news article with no details. You are filling in the details with your personal speculation. I'm not speculating on anything. I've provided facts that provide more context which you are rejecting. You're engaging in "slippery slope" fallacies and taking one example case, with no details, and expanding it to a general case with specificity that you, yourself, provide. That's not logical either. Your actual facts are wrong. Your speculations are off-the-mark, and your supporting "facts" aren't facts at all. And you won't alter your stance.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot ensure that the device is 100% protected, the same way that you cannot 100% ensure that nobody could ever break into an apartment, get access to your bank account etc.

It is instead always a trade-off between costs on one side and security on the other. Costs can involve the actual money, but it also involves usability, efficiency ... . To find the right balance you need to understand your actual risks which depend both on your personal situation and the value of the data. Messages containing just food recipes usually have a low value even in repressive countries, while messages which show conflicts with the government might be of low sensitivity in some countries but might be considered very sensitive in others.

So, if the government is interested in your data then you need to have different protections than if only your friend is too nosy. Phones are usually designed for high usability while still providing sufficient protection in face of attackers with limited resources - which includes limits on knowledge, money, time, ... needed to break into your phone. If the value of the data on your phone is low then it will not be worth for attackers to invest lots of resources to break into the phone, and this is true for governments too.

And even if you get a real secure device with lots of digital locks protecting your information which make it really hard even for you to get access, then there can simply be non-digital ways to force you to reveal this information - even if these might be illegal in some places. So you cannot assume that information are safe just because they are stored on a seemingly safe device. [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/538/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most people seem to have this binary opinion of whether the government can/can't break into phones/computer/encryption/etc but it is a lot more nuanced than that. The more important question is can they be bothered and also something not really talked about called "public interest".

If you are selling a bit of dope out of your apartment and the Police come a knocking and find that your phone is encrypted out the wazoo are they going to be bothered to break into it to find out the names of a few local drug users? Is it in the public interest to spend resources in order to identify such people? Probably not. On the other hand if the Police come a knocking because you are planning the next 9/11, they are going to be a lot more motivated, plus there is also a strong public interest to get into your devices. They will have a blank cheque to do anything to get into it. So the first question is whether what you are being investigated for is worth the time and money.

You mention the Apple incident. Apple actually refused to help the FBI break into that specific phone and further refused requests from the FBI to build backdoors into future IOS versions. The FBI went to Cellebrite who employ a number of very clever people and Cellebrite built a tool to get around Apple's encryption. Ultimately this is what companies like Cellebrite do and this is how they make their money. It comes down to the age old arms race of building a more secure system and the other team figuring out how to break it (take safe manufacturers vs safe crackers for instance).

Ultimately some of the premises upon which you build your question are flawed (such as companies helping the government every time), but the reality is against a motivated enough attacker with unlimited resources no device is 100% secure. Basically you encrypt your phone/data for the same reason you lock your car/house - it offers *some* protection against *some* people.

Comment: How is the premise of having the company help the government flawed? Apple is an American company and while they can fight warrants in certain cases, they cannot magically refuse to suddenly cooperate with the government.

https://toronto.ctvnews.ca/police-went-to-apple-offices-to-access-rob-ford-friend-s-iphone-1.1743787

This is a  Canadian case, but i'm sure many American warrants have also been served. I'm willing to bet Samsung would cooperate too.

Comment: I believe this is the Apple iPhone case you are referring to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple%E2%80%93FBI_encryption_dispute
Apple did in fact fight the validity of the court order. Given that the FBI withdrew the matter before judgement means that there is no precedent set for whether these types of court order are valid or not. As such the premise that Apple cooperated in anyway is flawed. The Toronto case you have linked (2014) predates the FBI one (2015&16) so it appears apple has changed their minds or the law is somehow different in the US.

Comment: But regardless of whether Apple does it or not, the entire point of relying on a company to decide whether to keep you safe or not doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: See my comment under your original post for more information about what the Apple thing was actually about because I don't think you fully understand the premise of what the FBI wanted. But ultimately you entrust your security to private companies in every facet of your life (be it digital or physical). And at the end of the day if you hide your data in a hole in the ground that no one knows about the wrench method (as pointed out above) is still very much available.

Comment: @ElizabethVogue "they cannot magically refuse to suddenly cooperate with the government" -- uh, yes, they really can. And Apple did just that: https://epic.org/documents/apple-v-fbi-2/. So, I don't think that you have a clear understanding about what a warrant is. And you've taken a complex technical and legal situation and boiled it down far too simply to be useful for discussion.

Comment: @schroeder Uh, no they really cannot. Warrants can be issued for any number of different things, so taking a single case and basing your entire argument on it like a blanket statement is in fact 'boiling it down too far'. I am telling you that in the presence of a criminal warrant for a specific phone device things will become more difficult, and the area more grey. Just because something is disputable in court does not reduce the power it has over getting certain data out of a device. If you are interested in discussion, I suggest you expand your scope of possible warrant implementation.

Comment: @ElizabethVogue If you actually have a read of the court documents in that Canadian case you keep mentioning. The warrant as it pertains to Apple states: "It is hereby further ordered that Apple shall provide reasonable technical assistance to enable law enforcement agents to obtain access to **unencrypted** data on the Device". It futher goes on to state "to the extent that data on the iOS device is encrypted, Apple may provide a copy of the encrypted data to law enforcement but is not required to attempt to decrypt or otherwise enable law enforcement to access any encrypted data"

Comment: @ElizabethVogue except that warrants are meaningless in terms of technical capability. And you are rejecting the "dot" that refutes your specific claim in this relevant example. So, you still appear to have magical thinking about warrants. and you are still missing the broader technical points. Your premise makes no sense, and there is little we can do to answer your question, which is sounding more and more like a general complaint than an actual technical question.

Comment: How does my premise make no sense? My entire thread is attempting to open a discussion on advanced encryption techniques that would withstand forensics by an entity with warrants or jurisdiction. You can't seem to accept this and are arguing incessantly and going off track. If you don't have the technical capabilities to answer my question or add something to it, then simply do not answer. it's that simple. You seem to think a legal warrant and jurisdiction make no difference at all in breaking into a phone. I disagree with you.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a place to "open a discussion on advanced encryption techniques that would withstand forensics". Your question literally is, "what's the point of protecting my phone?" If you are wanting to "open a discussion" then your question is too open-ended. And since you are rejecting all attempts to make this question about the facts and not your feelings around the issue, I'm closing as unanswerable.